# What is the anti derivative of $ f(x) = \int\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}dx $?

Tags: integration

I know u-substitution and integration by parts, but I don't know how to solve this one.

Comment: Do you want the anti-derivative of $\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ or the anti-derivative of $f(x)$ defined above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\log f(x)+C$$

and

$$\frac1{1+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$$

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews, edited.

Comment: It was edited by someone else correcting a mistake that made another mistake...

Answer (score 2):

Try multiplying the top and bottom of this fraction by $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u = 1 + e^{-x}$ and use partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}dx=\int\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{e^x}}dx=\int\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}dx\\u=e^x+1\\du=e^x\;dx\Longrightarrow dx=\frac{du}{e^x}\\\int\frac{e^x}{u}\cdot\frac{du}{e^x}=\int\frac{du}{u}=\ln|u|+C=\ln|e^x+1|+C$$